# Will this modern road bike hub fit in my 1990's MTB (130mm restoration)

Tags: wheels, wheel-building, conversion, restoration

I have a mid 1990's MTB with 130mm OLD between dropouts. In order to fit a 9 speed Hyperglide cassette I switched the wheel for a modern 135mm and removed spacers on the non drive side. Works like a charm, it is effectively 131mm and the wheel fits without touching because it's a MTB chainstay with road tyres. The problem is the wheel is off centred and I don't want to dish with the spokes.

I am now looking to build a new wheel for this bike, 130mm, 9 speed Hyperglide Freehub, all nicely centred. It will be mounted on a 26 inches MTB rim for V-brakes with 1.5 tyres.

[Will this road bike hub do the trick or do I need something else? Suggestion welcome!](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/304122829419?hash=item46cf221a6b:g:BkwAAOSwHmlhKOGZ)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it will work without issue.

To make it work with 7-speed you'll just use a 4.5mm spacer that's made for the purpose behind the cassette.